# Windows App service: HTTP works, but not HTTPS (vb.net or c#)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows

I'm building a Cortana Windows 10 App (mainly for learning purposes).

The code below works for HTTP with username and password, but HTTPS doesn't work.  Any ideas?  My server uses a self-signed certificate and only outputs plain text (no HTML).  The code also runs as a service that is accessed by Cortana (not sure if this matters, but I've had issue with multiple awaits in the service, while placing them in the app works).

I tried using a post command, but couldn't get it to work.

```
                        Dim sResult = "No server response."

                    ' if any values are blank, alert user to set up app
                    If sServerAddress = "" OrElse sServerPort = "" OrElse sGUID = "" Then
                        sResult = "You must open the Control Home app first, configure server settings, and then click Set Values to store server settings.  Click below to go to the app."
                    Else

                        ' TO DO: check for valid URI

                        Dim oURI As Uri = New Uri(sServerAddress + ":" + sServerPort + "/sys/%7B" + sGUID + "%7D?d??mbNaturalLanguage(" + command + ")")

                        ' the below options set up username and password, and should allow SSL certificates that are self-signed
                        Dim oFilter = New HttpBaseProtocolFilter()
                        oFilter.ServerCredential = New Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential(oURI.ToString(), sUsername, sPassword)
                        oFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Expired)
                        oFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted)
                        oFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.InvalidName)
                        'oFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Success)
                        'oFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Revoked)
                        'oFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.IncompleteChain)
                        'oFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.InvalidSignature)
                        'oFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.InvalidCertificateAuthorityPolicy)
                        'oFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.BasicConstraintsError)
                        'oFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.UnknownCriticalExtension)
                        'oFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.RevocationInformationMissing)
                        'oFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.RevocationFailure)
                        'oFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.BasicConstraintsError)
                        'oFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.OtherErrors)
                        Try
                            Dim oHTTP As Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient = New Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(oFilter)
                            sResult = Await oHTTP.GetStringAsync(oURI)
                            oHTTP.Dispose()
                            ' End If
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            sResult = "Error: " + ex.HResult.ToString("X") + " Message: " + ex.Message
                        End Try
                    End If

                    ' read message
                    Await SendCompletionMessageForPhone(sResult)
```

Comment: Forgot to say the error stored in sResult that Cortana reads back is:  Error 80190194 Message: Not found (404).  Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you get the same failure if you request a https page with a valid, non-self-signed certificate, just to test it? (IE, have you confirmed that it's only happening for self-signed certificates, or all https requests?)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may occur because self-signed certificates are not originated from a Trusted Source, and some browsers understand it as a Phishing Website - may be Cortana understands it and block the connection.

I recommend buy a cheap SSL certificate to protect your site and allows you to conduct that kind of tests.

Be sure also your certificate is viewed by machine, not the website (if using IIS7 and above).